# Ошибка при компиляции проекта angular

Tags: angular2, angular4, angular5, angular

Доброго времени суток.

При компиляции проекта у меня вылетает вот такая ошибка:

```
Date: 2018-06-23T07:09:31.526Z
Hash: 850794f8281827da9d4b
Time: 4886ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 2.15 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 5.22 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 10.3 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 326 kB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in src/app/services/task.ts(46,5): error TS2322: Type 'Promise<void | Task>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<Task>'.
Type 'void | Task' is not assignable to type 'Task'.
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Task'.

ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

Ругается на этот участок кода:

```
42    create(task): Promise<Task> {
43      task['due_date'] = task['due_date']['formatted'];
44      let body = JSON.stringify({task: task});
45      const url = `${this.tasksUrl}?access_token=${localStorage.getItem('token')}`;
46      return this.http.post(url, body, { headers: this.headers })
47       .toPromise()
48       .then(res => res.json() as Task)
49       .catch(error => {
50        this.handleError(error, 'Could not create task!')
51      });
52    }
```

Подскажите что не так.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в несовпадении типов. Функция `create` возвращает тип `Promise<Task>`, а на 46-й строке конструкция `this.http.post` может вернуть как `Task`, так и `void`.

Возможны такие варианты:

- Изменить возвращаемый тип функции `create` на `Promise<void | Task>`, это будет выглядеть так: `create(task): Promise<void | Task> {...}`. Этот вариант чреват тем, что переменной, которой будет присваиваться результат выполнения `create` тоже не ожидает получить `void | Task`, тогда по цепочке пойдут изменения.
- Железно вернуть тип `Promise<Task>`. В этом случае нужно проверять тип того, что возвращает `this.http.post`:

  ```
  let request: any = this.http.post(url, body, {headers: this.headers});

  if ( !(request instanceof Task) ) {
    request = new Task(); // здесь делаете что-то что вернёт Promise<Task>.
    // Обратите внимание, new Task() сработает, только если
    // вы в конструкторе класса Task прописали вариант создания
    // экземпляра без входных данных.
  }
  ```